# how to prevent from deleting old file in excel by python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am a total beginner in Python.

I wrote a program which is get the table from the website by selenium in webscrapping. Save it in to the excel file at the end open this excel file , edited some of the data in column make it standard for our DATABASE then save it in to the another excel file.

I need these chapters  **02,04,10,11,12,15,20,23,38**

Each chapter has for example 23 more or less pages of the tables.

The problem which I have is that whenever it save in first excel file any previous chapter eliminated. AT THE END I have just **chapter **38**** in my first Excel and second Excel file.

I really wonder if anybody can help me.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import os, platform
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time

#  Clear the screen
def clear():
   if platform.system() == 'Windows':
      os.system('cls')
   else:
      os.system('clear')
#  For Making the Pretty Table in the first Page
columns = ["Please Enter your number for each country", ""]
myTable = PrettyTable()
myTable.add_column(columns[0],["1- Canada", "2- United Kingdom","3- South Korea","4- Turkey","5- New Zealand"])
myTable.add_column(columns[1],["","","","",""])
print(myTable)

#------------((Canada- Import Procedure, For selecting the the chapters and retrieve the data))----------------
def Canada_Im():
    Ca_Im_Start_Year  = input("Start Year like '20XX':")
    Ca_Im_Start_Month = input("Start Month like 'X':")
    Ca_Im_End_Year = input("End Year like '20XX':")
    Ca_Im_End_Month= input("End month like 'X':")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/pub/71-607-x/71-607-x2021004-eng.htm')
    time.sleep(2)
    #  for clicking the import button
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="cimt_import"]/p[1]/a').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    #  for clicking the Data Extraction button
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="topic3s"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    #  for clicking the Start Year, month & End Year, month button
    # Start year
    dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id('fromYear')
    dd = Select(dropdown)
    dd.select_by_value(str(Ca_Im_Start_Year))
    # Start month
    dropdown_fM = driver.find_element_by_id('fromMonth')
    dd_fM = Select(dropdown_fM)
    dd_fM.select_by_value(str(Ca_Im_Start_Month))
    # End year
    dropdown_tY = driver.find_element_by_id('toYear')
    dd_tY = Select(dropdown_tY)
    dd_tY.select_by_value(str(Ca_Im_End_Year))
    # End month
    dropdown_tM = driver.find_element_by_id('toMonth')
    dd_tM = Select(dropdown_tM)
    dd_tM.select_by_value(str(Ca_Im_End_Month))

    # Commodity: Specific Commodity filed
    dropdown_rH = driver.find_element_by_id('report_hs')
    dd_rH = Select(dropdown_rH)
    dd_rH.select_by_value("1") 

    # Commodity: Specific Chapter
    ch_numbers = ["02","04","10","11","12","15","20","23","38"]
    for ch_number in ch_numbers:
        dropdown_rC = driver.find_element_by_id('report_chapters')
        dd_rC = Select(dropdown_rC)
        dd_rC.select_by_value(ch_number) 
    
        #  for retriving the data and store it in the excel form
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="report"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/p[2]/button').click()
        time.sleep(3)
        Canada_Result=[]
        pages = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="paginate_button" or @class="paginate_button current" and @title]'))
        pages = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@onclick and @class="paginate_button" or @class="paginate_button current" and @title][%d]' % (pages)).text.strip("Page\n")

        if pages == '':
            pages = 1

        for J in range (int(pages)):
            commodities = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[2]/a')
            Countries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[4]')
            quantities = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[7]')
            weights = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="report_table"]/tbody/tr["i"]/td[8]/abbr')
            time.sleep(2)
            period_entries = len(commodities)
            time.sleep(1)
            for i in range(period_entries):
                temporary_data= {'Commodity': commodities[i].text,'Country': Countries[i].text,'quantity': quantities[i].text, 'weight': weights[i].text }
                Canada_Result.append(temporary_data)
            df_data = pd.DataFrame(Canada_Result)
            df_data
            df_data.to_excel('Canada_scrapping_result.xlsx', index=False)
            

            if J == int(pages) - 1:
                print("Done")
                break
            # click on the Next button
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="report_results_next"]').click()
            time.sleep(1)
        #----------for convert the data in excel and save it again---------------
            df = pd.read_excel('Canada_scrapping_result.xlsx') 
        for i in range(len(df[df.columns[0]])):
            string = df["Commodity"][i]
            split_str = string.split("—")  # Splits string at "—"
            number = split_str[0] 
            df['Commodity'][i] = number.replace(".", "") 
            df['Commodity'][i] = df['Commodity'][i][:-5]
            df.to_csv("Remove_characters.csv")
    

        time.sleep(1)
        # Click Submit
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="report"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/p[2]/button').click()
        time.sleep(2)
# ******************************************************************************
# -------------------------((Canada Main Page))------------------------------
def canada_function():
    # for chosing import or export function
    clear()
    columns = ["Please Choose Import or Export For CANADA",""]
    myTable_canada = PrettyTable()
    myTable_canada.add_column(columns[0],["1- import", "2- export"])
    myTable_canada.add_column(columns[1],["",""])
    print(myTable_canada)
    print("\n")
    canada_Im_Ex=input("Im/Ex:")

    match canada_Im_Ex:
        case "1":
            Canada_Im()
        case "2":
            print("Please Enter month:")
# for getting the country Code
country_number=input("number:")

match country_number:
    case "1":
        clear()    
        print("Canada")
        canada_function()
    case "2":
        print("United Kingdom")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the starting row for `panda.DataFrame.to_excel()`, or else it will always starts at the first row, removing old data. See [panda documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Which means, you should specify the starting row by something like this in your case:

```py
df_data.to_excel('Canada_scrapping_result.xlsx', index=False, startrow=your_row_int_here)
```

Or pass an [ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) object instead of the file name, which can be created with `mode='a'`, which is append mode and should be what you needed

Comment: May I ask you to see my total codes. I edited and you can see the whole of it. Then please give me your suggestion.

Comment: @SaeidVaygani See my updated answer, I suggest using the [pandas.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) with append mode